# How to implement a ServiceLocator with generics?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

Having this interface:

```
public interface ServiceLocator {
    <T> void setService(Class<T> klass, Factory<T> factory)

    <T> void setConstant(Class<T> klass, T value)

    <T> T getObject(Class<T> klass)

}
```

How do I implement it? I mean, how I declare the structure data?
Is this right?

```
private Map<Class, Factory> services = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: That's the way, you could still add wildcards to get rid of raw-type warnings. ```Map<Class<?>, Factory<?>>```.

Comment: But isn't the point of using generics to have secure types? I'm refering to my `constants`declaration that has Object type. Having that, when I do `getObject` of a constant then I'm forced to do a cast:                                                      `(T) constants.get(klass);` And that isn't right, isn't it?

Comment: You can't get that level of security through the type system. But you already have (most of) it in the form of encapsulation.

Comment: There is no safe way to have a Map return a different generic type for each key.

Comment: The Java type system isn't powerful enough to prove that what you're doing is type safe.  You can prove that for yourself, and use unsafe casts to hide that from the type system, but that's the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: Ook, I get it. I have another question. What should I do to get a factory? This: `Factory f = services.get(klass);` or this: `Factory<T> f = services.get(klass);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Factory<?>> services = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class<?>, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
```

Adding `-Xlint:unchecked` directive to the compiler options.
And `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the methods where you need it. In my case is on `getObject` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<Class, Factory> services = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
```

If you wanna use this structures you can declare it like that:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Factory<T>> services = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class<?>, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
```

Remember to put `Factory<T>` to catch the type.
Using Class provides you to use AnyClass.class as Key

Btw you can put all in one Map like `private Map<Class<?>, Object>` and at the get function cast it if it's a Factory or not ;)

Comment: `Map<Class<?>, Factory<T>> services` it can not be, because I don't want the implementation to be generic, only the methods. And put all in one map is an option but I prefer otherwise, it's the same but cleaner, isn't it?

Comment: Well yes it's more cleaner with two maps if it's that case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Guava has an interface intended for a similar purpose: [`ClassToInstanceMap<B>`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#classtoinstancemap).  The API is:

```
<T extends B> T getInstance(Class<T> type);
<T extends B> T putInstance(Class<T> type, T value);
```

Looking at the implementation in [`MutableClassToInstanceMap.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/com/google/common/collect/MutableClassToInstanceMap.java/), we see that it uses a `HashMap<Class<? extends B>, B>` wrapped in a `ConstrainedMap`.  Its `MapConstraint` uses [`java.lang.Class.cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) to ensure that all the values in the map are legal instances of their corresponding keys.

Since `B` is often just `Object`, the implementation's `HashMap` ends up just being a `HashMap<Class<? extends Object>, Object>`.